# How to open a URL to work with on javascript script file?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a list of URLs, which every URLs contain a certain form.

for example , every URL contain "#msg" textbox, and "#form" form.

So I want to fill the `"msg` with `"txt"`, and then submit - `document.getElementById("form").submit()`.

## My question:

How do I open the URL for doing the above?

I don't want to really open the URL. just submit the form.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't clear. Probably you are not speaking about an URL. Why do you say ' not really open ' ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I know I'm not clear. I'm trying to post a message to vBulletin forum using a script

Comment: Must it be javascript ? I would use PHP and curl using sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit only the data, without displaying the form, you could use ajax to post the data to the action URL of the form.

This means that you cannot directly use your list, but that you must first inspect the forms on each of those pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an ajax request to pull in the html of the form, and then build the dom, and then populate the textbox and submit the form from your current page. After that rinse and repeat for each url. This would require that the pages are on your domain.